# Отличия между enum в C и в C++

Tags: c++, c, enum, int

Правильно ли я понимаю, что `C++`, в отличии от `C`, запрещает неявное приведение между `enum` и `int`?

И верно ли, что в `C++` в одной области видимости может находиться два разных перечисления, которые содержат элементы с одинаковым именем? На сколько я помню, в `C` такое запрещено, поскольку в `C` `enum` очень близок к обычному `define`.

Comment: Если использовать `enum class MyEnum{...};` то да, если обычный `enum MyEnum{...};` то вроде всё то же самое что и в Си

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В языке С значения разных enum-типов свободно приводятся друг к другу, а также к целочисленным типам и обратно. Это также означает немедленную применимость к enum-значениям всех встроенных арифметических операторов.

```
enum E { A, B, C };
E a = A;
a++;       // OK
a = a - 1; // OK
```

Тем не менее enum-типы являются самостоятельными типами: неявного приведения между *указателями* на разные enum-типы, а также к/из *указателей* на целочисленные типы в языке нет.

Язык С не допускает "предварительных" enum-объявлений, т.е. enum-объявлений без перечисления enum-констант

```
enum E; // Ошибка в С
```

---

В С++ есть два типа `enum`: scoped и unscoped. Unscoped enum помещает имена констант в охватывающую область видимости (как в С), т.е. два unscoped enum-типа в одной и той же области видимости не могут объявлять одно и то же имя константы. Scoped enum создает свою собственную область видимости.

При этом стоит заметить, что даже unscoped enum в С++ поддерживает "scoped" синтаксис обращения к своим константам

```
enum E { A }; // Unscoped enum
E e1 = A;     // Можно так
E e2 = E::A;  // и так тоже можно
```

В С++ запрещено неявное приведение значений целочисленных типов к любым enum-типам, что также автоматически блокирует использование тех встроенных операторов, которые в С работали через целочисленный тип в качестве промежуточного

```
enum E { A, B, C };
E a = A;
int x = a; // OK
a++;       // Ошибка в С++
a = a - 1; // Ошибка в С++
```

В С++ также запрещено неявное приведение значений scoped enum-типов к целочисленным типам, т.е. с точки зрения стандартных неявных приведений scoped enum-типы "изолированы" от других типов во всех направлениях.

```
enum class E { A, B, C };
E a = E::A;
int x = a; // Ошибка в С++
```

Также в С++ у вас есть возможность явно задавать "подлежащий" целочисленный тип, на основе которого будет представляться enum. (Если подлежащий целочисленный тип scoped enum не указан, то используется тип `int`.) При явном преобразовании "посторонних" целочисленных значений к такому enum-типу преобразование будет проходить по общим правилам преобразований к подлежащему целочисленному типу, в том числе в ситуациях, когда исходное значение не помещается в целевой диапазон.

Если подлежащий целочисленный тип unscoped enum не указан, то он выбирается автоматически. Однако в таком случае, если при явном преобразовании "посторонних" целочисленных значений к такому enum-типу исходное значение не попадает в целевой диапазон, то поведение не определено.

В С++ у вас есть возможность делать "opaque enum declarations", т.е. enum-объявления без перечисления enum-констант, если подлежащий тип enum фиксирован

```
enum E : unsigned; // OK в С++
```

Answer (score 6):

> Правильно ли я понимаю, что C++, в отличии от C, запрещает неявное
>   приведение между enum и int?

В С и С++ `enum` работает идентично(если говорить о неявном преобразовании к `int`).

```
enum A {Yes, No};
...
int a = A::Yes;
```

Даний код работает прекрасно(для С++).

```
 enum A {Yes, No};
 ...
 enum A a = Yes;
 int ea = a;
```

Даний код работает прекрасно(для С).

В С++ есть `enum class` в котором данный трюк не пройдет.
Но неявно по умолчанию используется `int`.

В обычного `enum` есть проблема с областью видимости.

```
enum Color{Red, Green, Blue};
```

`Red`, `Green`, `Blue` видно без использования `Color`.

> И верно ли, что в C++ в одной области видимости может находиться два
>   разных перечисления, которые содержат элементы с одинаковым именем?

Да, если `enum class`

Нет, если `enum`

[enum in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumeration-enum-c/)

[enum in C++](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/enumeration)

[enum class in C++](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/4-5a-enum-classes/)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.